# Global Search in groups return Limited Result

Tags: telegram, telegram-api, wtelegramclient

this code search in telegram globally and return Groups

```
var t = ((await  client.Messages_SearchGlobal("Keyword")) as Messages_MessagesSlice).chats.Where(q=>q.Value.IsGroup).ToList();
```

but it returns limited result (just 5 group) . also we know that there are more GROUPS in telegram with this keyword.
how fetch all groups or more in telegram Api ?

Edit:

adding Limit and offset also return limited result and Duplicate Result:

```
var asdfdsf = ((await  client.Messages_SearchGlobal("Keyword",limit:20)) as Messages_MessagesSlice);
            while (asdfdsf.flags== Messages_MessagesSlice.Flags.has_next_rate)
            {
                asdfdsf = ((await client.Messages_SearchGlobal("Keyword", offset_rate: asdfdsf.next_rate, limit: 20)) as Messages_MessagesSlice);
                var asdfdsfsdf = asdfdsf.chats.Where(q => 

q.Value.IsGroup).ToList();
}
```

Comment: you have to use `offset` and `limit` parameters

Comment: i have Added offset and limit but it returns Duplicate Result. Question Edited

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you trying to search for keywords in: 1. Messages from the user's joined groups/channels, 2. Names of public groups/channels in Telegram, or 3. Messages in all of Telegram public groups/channels?

Comment: I want number 2

Answer (score 0):

`Messages_SearchGlobal` is used to search within messages from the group/channel the user has already joined.

The method you're looking for is [`Contacts_Search`](https://corefork.telegram.org/method/contacts.search) which returns public groups & channels (& users) having a given name (including some partial match)

Comment: it retun just 9 Result and has no any pagination, Screenshot : [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYiNs.jpg) but `Messages_SearchGlobal` return limted global search  just like official telegram application :[Official](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R50mW.jpg) . `Messages_SearchGlobal`  has pagination and `Contacts_Search` has no pagination.

Comment: Yes, usually you can't do more with API calls than what you can do in official Telegram app.

Comment: i didnt find any solution yet , for getting more poulic search in telegram channel and account , is there any full sample ?